# Trigger to assist data integration, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: apex, trigger, api, integration, campaign-member

I'm working with Wordpress/Gravity Forms to grab some user data and insert it as a member of a campaign. The integration piece is working (for the most part) but I'm having trouble with one thing. Obviously the user won't be able to fill out their contact's Salesforce ID, so I'm writing a trigger to match the email entered to the contact in salesforce, then set the ContactID in the CampaignMember to be the Contact ID.
Here's my trigger:

```
trigger FindAssignCampaignMember on CampaignMember (before insert) {
    list<CampaignMember> cms = new List<CampaignMember>([Select Id, ContactId, Email__c from CampaignMember where Id in :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()]);
    set<String> Ctcts = new set<String>();
    System.debug(Ctcts);
    for (CampaignMember cm : cms){ctcts.add(cm.Email__c);}
    map<ID, Contact> cmp = new map<ID, Contact>([select Id, name, Email from Contact where Email in :ctcts]);
    CampaignMember[] cmex;
    if (Trigger.isDelete) 
        cmex = Trigger.old;
    else
        cmex = Trigger.new; 
    for (CampaignMember cme : cmex){
        for (Contact cmps : cmp.values()){
             if(cmps.Email == cme.Email__c){cme.ContactId = cmps.Id;}
        }

    } 
}
```

When I run my unit test i'm getting

```
(7397681895)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[85]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, FindAssignCampaignMember: execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Problem is, I can't figure out where the null pointer reference is coming from.
I think a likely culprit would be the ctcts set, but I'm having trouble trying to get it to print the variable in the logs so I can check it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel it is be cmex that is causing a null pointer. change     CampaignMember[] cmex; to     CampaignMember[] cmex = new CampaignMember[] (); and rerun the test class

Comment: Rao, that was the reason for the null pointer. When I modified it like you said I was able to successfully run the unit test. I actually cleaned the whole thing up with a lot of help from Crop1645 though, so the final product doesn't look like this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- here is a rewritten trigger with some clearer (to me) variable names

Since this is a before insert trigger, you don't need to test for `isDelete`.  You also don't need to query for the CME as `Trigger.new` has the values

This presumes that Contacts already exist for the CME's email field value.

Your logic also presumes (and I left that alone) that no two Contacts share the same email and if they do, you don't care which Contact is associated to the CME

lastly, your logic could be made faster (exercise for you) by creating a map of emailToContact and then you wouldn't need to scan every found Contact for every CME. There could be 200 CME in a batch and hence 200 contacts so that is a lot of iterations.

```
trigger FindAssignCampaignMember on CampaignMember (before insert) {

  set<String> emailSearchSet = new set<String>();
  for (CampaignMember cm : Trigger.new)  // build list of unique emails
      emailSearchSet.add(cm.Email__c);

  map<ID, Contact> cidToContactMap = new map<ID, Contact>([select Id, name, Email 
                   from Contact where Email in :emailSearchSet]); // find matching Contacts
  map<String,Contact> emailToContactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();

 // Build efficient lookup map
 for (Contact c: cidToContactMap.values())
    emailToContactMap.put(c.email.toLowercase(),c); // presumes all Contacts have emails. If not, you have to test for null

 for (CampaignMember cme : Trigger.new) //go back through new CME ..
    cme.contactId = cme.email != null   // for CMes with non null emails
        ? emailToContactMap.containsKey(cme.email.toLowercase()) // is there a Contact?
           ? emailToContactMap.get(cme.email.toLowercase()).id // the Contact ID
           : null  // no Contact with the CME's email
        : null;  // no email in CME      


}
```

Comment: Awesome. It passes my unit test successfully. I'm going to work on putting in the email to contact map now.

Comment: Crop1645- any chance you could point me toward documentation that's helpful for maps? I'm a novice at apex.

Comment: I updated my answer - not syntax-checked; it could even be tighter code but this will be adequate

Comment: I'll learn from your post rather than simply copying and pasting. Much appreciated!

Comment: Basically we're looping over the cidToContact Map and mapping the email as the key and then the contact as the value correct?
Then, we loop over trigger.new.

I'm pretty lost on the syntax of the checks in the final loop-
Is this some kind of if-else structure?

Comment: Shorthand if syntax. Got it. VERY cool/educational thanks!

Comment: bcarlock -- Q1 - correct; Q2 - you should read the Apex Doc, the `=`,  `?` and `:` are part of what is called a ternary expression (shorthand for if-else)

Comment: If I could throw more props your way I would. This is absolutely by far the most educational and helpful experience I've had on stackexchange to date.
**Thanks!**

Comment: you can always vote up good answers throughout SFSE (mine and others)! But seriously, we're all here to help as we've been through this before in your shoes. If you demonstrate that you've tried, you'll get good help here

Comment: I always upvote helpful answers! But, if this were reddit I'd buy you gold or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work in a before insert trigger because the IDs for CampaignMember have not been assigned yet and trigger.newMap is null.

```
  list<CampaignMember> cms = new List<CampaignMember>([Select Id, ContactId, Email__c from CampaignMember where Id in :Trigger.newMap.KeySet()]);
```